# How to use Glyphs 3 to set the lowest y value of a character set to the descender (i.e. size to fit)

Tags: fonts, font-design, glyphs

I've bought the licenses of a few fonts to put in an app I'm making like this:

[image]

You can see that there is a lot of excess space at the bottom and the font is quite small. So I downloaded the free trial of Glyphs 3 and saw that the fonts descender is -200 yet none of the character's minimum y values come even close to going that low.

My ultimate question is, is there a way in Glyphs to find the lowest y point a character reaches for the entire character set and then set the descender to that value? Would also like to do this for the ascender as well (for the highest y point).

Essentially I'm wanting to "size to fit" the font so that it doesn't have too much excess space at the bottom or top.

Comment: I might be missing something, but it seems like an extreme overkill to change the font file to make a visual change in your app. Why can't you just increase the font size?

Comment: I’m sure you could script it, if nothing else, though my knowledge of both Python and the Glyphs object model is not even close to being up to scratch for it. The best place to ask if you want a quick reply is probably the [Glyphs forum](https://forum.glyphsapp.com) where Georg (the app developer) and Rainer (mekkablue) in particular are very helpful.

Comment: @Wolff Increasing the font size in iOS will also increase the descender, so if a font has excess space at the bottom, that will also increase.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the info, going to hit them up.

Comment: It's CSS right? Then move a little bit down with some value set in the *top* property? You only need to find the offset once and then set the value in em so it will work for all font sizes.

Comment: @Wolff It's an iOS App so it's in Objective C. Manually repositioning is a lot of work because I have 88 fonts with different metrics in the app (I've tried to do all I can in the code but have found it's more efficient to just edit the file).

Comment: OK, I understand. (88 fonts in one app though? Must be a font app.)